# Two questions regarding the angle of reflection

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have two problems regarding the calculation of angles given certain values.

In the first problem I need to calculate the angle X given that both angles Y are identical

[image: Problem 1]

In the second problem I need to calculate the angles Z where both Z's are identical

[image: Problem 2]

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For the first one, note that the two triangles are similar. How much of the 80 units on the bottom is in each triangle? For the second one, try drawing a vertical at the point where the path hits the top line and perform a similar analysis.

Comment: @Mac89: Thank you for taking the hint and running with it :)